# Why is program not getting executed at given scheduled time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

```
import time,datetime

startTime = datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 20, 23, 0, 0)
while datetime.datetime.now() < startTime:       
    time.sleep(1)

print('Program now starting on 20 NOV 2016 @ 23:00')
```

Comment: Because the time difference (at least in my timezone) is around 4 hours. Make `startTime` one minute ahead of the current time and it executes just fine after the minute elapses.

Comment: i checked my datetime.datetime.now() . It is not working even after changing by an hour

Comment: @Runjhun, try to print `startTime` and `datetime.datetime.now()` to see if their values are the ones expected. Also don't expect your program to be executed precisely the time you are specifing, cause it won't till the `time.sleep(1)` expires.

Comment: Runjhun, it working as per the code; if you don't forget to keep the `startTime` just ahead of the current time as mentioned by Jim above. Don't make it too ahead of current time for testing. 1 or 2 min gap is fine. I have tested it that way and i am in your time zone (IST). I suggest for ease of use changing the print line with this. `print('Program now starting on ' + str(startTime.date()) + ' @ ' + str(startTime.time()))`

Comment: But its working on my computer. Exact thing copy pasted only changed `startTime` just 1 min. ahead. lol weird problem even we are at same timezone. Wait what exacty is the time showing in your pc right now?

Comment: Tanmaya did u try putting a time 2 min ahead of current time?

Comment: just tried. Needed a little patience. Its working. Hey if you are in Linux; use this command `timedatectl` commandline and see the IST and UTC times? Also, see if your NTP is synchronised?

Comment: its not linux...
can u please paste the exact program which is working for you ?

Comment: its the same you have posted, haven't changed anything except keeping the `startTime` a little ahead. Is it windows? then set your timezone and sync your network time will probably help. I have no idea about windows time setting though.

Comment: Thank You so Much...it atleast started working..i will try syncing it more properly :)